# CActiveRecord::findall throws exception

Tags: yii

I'm trying to perform a search in one of my tables based on a given criteria like so:

```
$id = 1;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition("usr_currency=:currency");
$currencies = User::model()->findAll($criteria, array(':currency' => $id,));
```

I get a `CDbException`:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: 
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound. 
The SQL statement executed was: 
    SELECT * FROM `user` `t` 
    WHERE usr_currency=:currency
```

Where as, this works:

```
$id = 1;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition("usr_currency=:currency");
$criteria->params = array(':currency' => $id,);
$comments = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

What is wrong with the first code fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CActiveRecord::find()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail)

> This is only used when the first parameter is a string (query condition). In other cases, please use CDbCriteria::params to set parameters.

Comment: Ah, I see. Doc for `findAll()` doesn't mention anything of this sort :)

Comment: From the `CActiveRecord::findAll()` explanation: Finds all active records satisfying the specified condition. See find() for detailed explanation about $condition and $params. :)